# how to send modified values to API

Tags: angular, typescript

i have modified values that i want to send to API,
how can i include finalDate variable to data? I am using reactive forms with mat-stepper single form thats why i am using formArray
this is my code:

```
  onSubmit() {
    const birthDateValue = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray).at(0).get("birthDate").value;
    const birthDateValueControl = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray).at(0).get("birthDate");
    const PeriodValue = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray).at(1).get("period");
    // send age as date
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
    date.setFullYear(year);
    const finalDate = date.toISOString();
    //set value of carousel
    PeriodValue.setValue(this.myCarousel.slideCounter + 3);
    // send form as one object
    const formArrayData = this.formGroup.get('formArray').value;
    const data = formArrayData.reduce((prev, next) => ({
      ...prev,
      ...next
    }), {})
    console.log(data);

    this.service.calculate(data).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a standard http library like httpClient

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

public postData() {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>('your.api.com', this.formgroup.value)
}
```